# ¿ Existe un evento para click sostenido en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, eventos, click, mouse

conocen algún evento en javascript que detecte cuando se hace click y se mantiene el click?, verán, deseo realizar una acción cantidad infinita de veces mientras se este haciendo click "mantenido- sostenido" a un elemento html, o tienen alguna idea de como se pordia hacer esto?, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: checate este llamado on release aqui un ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousedown

Answer (score 4):

Observa este código.

La primera función se ejecuta mientras el botón está presionado.

La segunda se ejecuta cuando se levanta el clic. Fíjate que calcula el tiempo transcurrido entre el click y su levantamiento, mediante una combinación de `onmousedown` y `onmouseup`.

Creo que con esto puedes hacer lo que quieres.

```js
var btnClick = document.getElementById('btnClick');
var startTime, endTime;

/*Cuando se haga clic*/
btnClick.onmousedown = function() {
  startTime = new Date();
  console.log("Estoy presionado, haz lo que necesites...");
};

/*Cuando se deje de hacer clic*/
btnClick.onmouseup = function() {
  endTime = new Date();
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //en ms
  console.log("Se hizo clic:\n" + startTime);
  console.log("Se levantó el clic:\n" + endTime);
  console.log("Tiempo transcurrido:\n" + timeDiff + " ms");
};
```

```html
<button id="btnClick">Haz Clic</button>
```